# How to add default value to django-markitup widget?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-widget

Friends,I want to add default value to django MarkItUpWidget

```
title = forms.CharField(max_length = 30)

    content = forms.CharField(widget=MarkItUpWidget())
```

Comment: You can't add 'default value' for widget because widgets don't have default values, they are just for rendering. Fields can have default (initial) values.

Answer (score 3):

The way to provide an initial value for unbound forms in Django is the `initial` argument.

```
content = forms.CharField(widget=MarkItUpWidget(), initial='initial value')
```

Comment: got error
content = forms.CharField(widget=MarkItUpWidget(initial = "initial"))

Comment: `initial` is an argument for the field, not the widget. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
set the value in the form definition:
 q = forms.CharField(label='search' widget=forms.TextInput(), initial=123)
```